# 2D rectangle sliding collision doesn't work

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl, collision, rectangles

So I'm developing a little escape game, and I want to make sure you can't walk through walls. I also want to be able to slide across walls. With this I mean that when you have a wall on your left, and you press left and up, you slide up but don't go through the wall. First I fabricated some buggy code which didn't work very well. After some searching on the internet I found this:

http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/59723.aspx

It sounded really logical and easy so I implemented it in my program. The problem is is that it still doesn't work, only very irregulary. Sometimes it allows you to slide (altough slower/faster than expected), sometimes you can only slide faster and sometimes you can't slide at all. My code looks like this:

```
bool cLevel::slideCol(SDL_Rect* pos, SDL_Rect* oldPos) {
    bool col = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < walls.size(); ++i) {
        if (rectCol(*pos, walls[i])) {
            pos->x = oldPos->x;
            col = true;
        }

        if (rectCol(*pos, walls[i])) {
            pos->y = oldPos->y;
            col = true;
        }
    }

    return col;
}
```

It checks all the walls against the current position. It first adjusts the x position, and if there still is a collision it adjusts the y position. You can get a demo here if you want to see my problem in action: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/65227065/Operation%20Get%20Out.zip . I'm pretty sure the rectCol function works, I've tested it thoroughly. But just to be sure, here is it anyway:

```
bool rectCol(SDL_Rect f, SDL_Rect s) {
    bool ret = false;

    int t1, r1, b1, l1;
    int t2, r2, b2, l2;

    t1 = f.y;
    r1 = f.x + f.w;
    b1 = f.y + f.h;
    l1 = f.x;

    t2 = s.y;
    r2 = s.x + s.w;
    b2 = s.y + s.h;
    l2 = s.x;

    // Er zijn vier situaties mogelijk: - rechtsonder1 overlapt linksboven2
    //                                  - linksonder1 overlapt rechtsboven2
    //                                  - linksboven1 overlapt rechtsonder2
    //                                  - rechtsboven1 overlapt linksonder2
    // Die worden hier elk individueel gechecked

    if (r1 > l2 && r1 < r2) { // rechts
        if (b1 > t2 && b1 < b2) { // onder1 overlapt linksboven2
            ret = true;
        } else if (t1 > t2 && t1 < b2) { // boven overlapt overlapt linksonder2
            ret = true;
        }
    } else if (l1 > l2 && l1 < r2) { // links
        if (b1 > t2 && b1 <= b2) { // onder1 overlapt rechtsboven2
            ret = true;
        } else if (t1 > t2 && t1 < b2) { // boven1 overlapt met rechtsonder2
            ret = true;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I'm at the end of my wits here. Maybe I'm just missing something very simple (I probably am, as always) but I just can't seem to figure this out. Hopefully you guys can help me or the "submit" problem will let me see the light.

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT] Ok so I tried my original approach again because I had a hunch. It turned out that my original system didn't work because in one function I was hopping back and forth between floating point coordinates and integer coordinates. So if this thread is found in the future by someone with a similar problem, then be sure you stick to one type: either integers or floats. That will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: You did something wrong. Debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rectCol` function indicates whether there has been a collision, but it does not distinguish between a collision in X and a collision in Y.

If there has been a collision, your `slideCol` function adjusts the X position even if the collision was entirely in Y. So you cannot slide along the floor or ceiling.

I don't know why the sliding is sometimes slower or faster "than expected". I see no reason for that in the code (and I will not experiment with your dll's), so I suspect that your expectation may be unrealistic.

Comment: Hmm, I have been thinking and there are a lot of cases in which my code doesn't work. As always, I have overlooked some things. Thanks for giving me a push in the right direction haha